# Can pip be used to install a standalone tool?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Background: I'm building a commandline tool in python and I'm looking at the best way to distribute it.

My question is: if I were to incorporate my tool into pypi, would the end user be able to "pip install" it and use it from the command line?  Or is pypi only a repo for libraries to be imported in python code?

Comment: They should be able to use it from the command line depending on how you package it

Comment: yes, you tend to use `scripts` or `console_scripts`, here's [an example from one of my projects](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/e717df0ba8fae74ecfe57e2f26a1cafc63c8735b/setup.py#L47-L53) which provides three executables